# PostGIS ST_Buffer a polyline?

Tags: postgis

I am trying to run a buffer around a polyline (geography).  My first attempt below (based on [ST_Buffer documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html):

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Geomfromtext(i30.geog),10,'endcap=round join=round');
```

gives an error:

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "i30"
ST_Geomfromtext(**^here**i30.geog)
```

Comment: The error message is correct -- You did not include a required FROM clause.  The examples you were working from don't include a FROM because a table isn't involved, but if you have a table, you need to reference it in the FROM: `SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Geomfromtext(i30.geog),10,'endcap=round join=round') FROM i30;`

Comment: Thanks, I added a from clause to the end of the statement.  i30 is a table.  SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Geomfromtext(i30.geog),10, 'endcap=round join=round')FROM i30;  Now getting a hint:  No function matches the given name and argument types.  You might need to add explicit type casts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's `i30`?  If it's a table, you'll need something like:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(geog,10,'endcap=round join=round') FROM i30;
```

and your result will have a buffered geography for each row in `i30`.

Comment: Toby..  looking back at the information in the example I changed my attempt. to the following.  SELECT ST_BUFFER(i30.geog, 10) FROM i30;  It worked.     THANKS.

Comment: yeah no need for ST_GeomFromtext when you have a geom field already...

Comment: Thanks, @mapBaker - I just pasted that from the question.  Now edited.